# How to upload assets to AWS presignedurl from ClientSide javascrript

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, pre-signed-url

I am approching presignedUrl method to upload a large file .

I call an API from my angular code to server side which gives me presignedUrl , then I need to upload an URL .

I have some question on this

1) Is there need to AWS SDK on my Angular side ?

I assume I dont need it , I just sent PUT request to unsigned URL and file

```
  uploadfileAWSS3old(e,f){    

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("data",JSON.stringify({name:"testname"}));
    formData.append("file", f.files[0]);

    let contentType = f.files["0"].type;

     const headers = new HttpHeaders(
       {
         'Content-Type': contentType
        });
     const req = new HttpRequest('PUT',this.URL,formData,
     {
       headers: headers,
       reportProgress: true, //This is required for track upload process
     });

     console.log(req)
      this.http.request(req)
        .subscribe(event=>{
          console.log(event)
        })

    }
```

But getting error of

> `SignatureDoesNotMatch`The request
>   signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
>   Check your key and signing
>   method.ASIAU7D2TEMAFBDCV3P5PUT
>
> image/jpeg 1533112061 x-amz-acl:authenticated-read
>   x-amz-security-token:FQoGZXIvYXdzEBoaDAqHuJwkAGpv42+GiiL5AeMmnOw3lETTKkYJNrcAC9BWzOuG0NW40sdXNqhYQWvNYacXZPUP8cXt2EQ/a95bMalAoUA1ZwF5U2H6wrjltrYmKkhOArtRuQ/E556o8hOfYts3l62AufhCEN+xr1ZoaX/uBIQMjhLTypP96rNesPc5cp9eT3CEG2tXa6q3nD6DaBh6tqX9ECTaoGAQHcW0Qm3oP+iIilUfft+7HmDc7ml6IH9utJwtJdfYuC6+v4fAcIhp60flapB8DIusKdvUumD1bik4WgXCsxSF4KyzPC0n1QdugXFb9EzYuXN1juXO3HQsYiVXkHMxByB5trMXkTsDBfw4uOAViij41oXbBQ==
>   /iclp-camp-qa.recipients.us-west-2/2b6224b9-8f33-48e8-8188-34149a659bea.cjk7zh9l9000001ozon5ziuik.cjkausvhx000001qe7jlssdu8.csvbzCxrflT/R7JzMcXcFccr3nrFCo=50 55 54 0a 0a 69 6d 61 67 65 2f 6a 70 65 67 0a 31 35 33 33 31 31 32 30
>   36 31 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 61 63 6c 3a 61 75 74 68 65 6e 74 69 63 61
>   74 65 64 2d 72 65 61 64 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 73 65 63 75 72 69 74 79
>   2d 74 6f 6b 65 6e 3a 46 51 6f 47 5a 58 49 76 59 58 64 7a 45 42 6f 61
>   44 41 71 48 75 4a 77 6b 41 47 70 76 34 32 2b 47 69 69 4c 35 41 65 4d
>   6d 6e 4f 77 33 6c 45 54 54 4b 6b 59 4a 4e 72 63 41 43 39 42 57 7a 4f
>   75 47 30 4e 57 34 30 73 64 58 4e 71 68 59 51 57 76 4e 59 61 63 58 5a
>   50 55 50 38 63 58 74 32 45 51 2f 61 39 35 62 4d 61 6c 41 6f 55 41 31
>   5a 77 46 35 55 32 48 36 77 72 6a 6c 74 72 59 6d 4b 6b 68 4f 41 72 74
>   52 75 51 2f 45 35 35 36 6f 38 68 4f 66 59 74 73 33 6c 36 32 41 75 66
>   68 43 45 4e 2b 78 72 31 5a 6f 61 58 2f 75 42 49 51 4d 6a 68 4c 54 79
>   70 50 39 36 72 4e 65 73 50 63 35 63 70 39 65 54 33 43 45 47 32 74 58
>   61 36 71 33 6e 44 36 44 61 42 68 36 74 71 58 39 45 43 54 61 6f 47 41
>   51 48 63 57 30 51 6d 33 6f 50 2b 69 49 69 6c 55 66 66 74 2b 37 48 6d
>   44 63 37 6d 6c 36 49 48 39 75 74 4a 77 74 4a 64 66 59 75 43 36 2b 76
>   34 66 41 63 49 68 70 36 30 66 6c 61 70 42 38 44 49 75 73 4b 64 76 55
>   75 6d 44 31 62 69 6b 34 57 67 58 43 73 78 53 46 34 4b 79 7a 50 43 30
>   6e 31 51 64 75 67 58 46 62 39 45 7a 59 75 58 4e 31 6a 75 58 4f 33 48
>   51 73 59 69 56 58 6b 48 4d 78 42 79 42 35 74 72 4d 58 6b 54 73 44 42
>   66 77 34 75 4f 41 56 69 69 6a 34 31 6f 58 62 42 51 3d 3d 0a 2f 69 63
>   6c 70 2d 63 61 6d 70 2d 71 61 2e 72 65 63 69 70 69 65 6e 74 73 2e 75
>   73 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 32 2f 32 62 36 32 32 34 62 39 2d 38 66 33 33 2d
>   34 38 65 38 2d 38 31 38 38 2d 33 34 31 34 39 61 36 35 39 62 65 61 2e
>   63 6a 6b 37 7a 68 39 6c 39 30 30 30 30 30 31 6f 7a 6f 6e 35 7a 69 75
>   69 6b 2e 63 6a 6b 61 75 73 76 68 78 30 30 30 30 30 31 71 65 37 6a 6c
>   73 73 64 75 38 2e 63 73
>   76750CAACBFE902B69CLf4hUHXcMFdTG8JqYtnxHUGZqiDhv17n3/qSFG3c8PtJYMhizUkAnOSIMypVzX0EEUl28ZCN2M=